# mysql: json based query

Tags: mysql, json

**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE t1(jdoc JSON);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{
       "data": 
       [
         {                      
            "type": "required",
            "member": {
                "id" : "1001",
                "response": "none"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "notrequired",
            "member": {
                "id" : "1009",
                "response": "accepted"
            }
        }
      ]            
 }');

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{
       "data": 
       [
         {                      
            "type": "maybe",
            "member": {
                "id" : "1002",
                "response": "none"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "maybe",
            "member": {
                "id" : "1003",
                "response": "accepted"
            }
        }
      ]
}');
```

I have two questions.

1. First is to get rows which has 1002 as memeber.id. I tried two queries for this and both are not working.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM t1 where JSON_CONTAINS(jdoc, JSON_QUOTE('1002'), '$.data[*].memeber.id');

   SELECT * FROM t1 where JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.data[*].memeber.id') = '1002';
   ```
2. Second is to get the rows which has type = 'required' and corresponding member.id = "1001"

Help me with the queries.

Comment: you have typo in your queries: memeber

Comment: @IgorVujovic yeah correct.. it should be "member"